# Servlet Filter - forwarded request from a servlet will go to servlet filter or not?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

If any `J2EE` application hit servlet directly and then servlet forward the same request to some `.jsp` page.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

And I have a servlet filter with below url-pattern

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>some_filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

So, will that forwarded request comes to filter also or not.

In my case it is not coming, is this a as expected behaviour. Just want to understand this.

Comment: Why down vote...? does not this question make sense?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want the filter mapping to be invoked for forward requests, you have to put this in web.xml

This support is there since Servlet2.4

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>myfilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/mypath/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

The supported values for dispatcher are :

- **REQUEST**: The request comes directly from the client. This is indicated by a `<dispatcher>` element with value `REQUEST`, or by the
  absence of any `<dispatcher>` elements.
- **FORWARD**: The request is being processed under a request dispatcher representing the Web component matching the `<url-pattern>` or `<servlet-name>` using a `forward()` call.
  This is indicated by a `<dispatcher>` element with value `FORWARD`.
- **INCLUDE**: The request is being processed under a request dispatcher representing the Web component matching the `<url-pattern>` or `<servlet-name>` using an `include()` call.
  This is indicated by a `<dispatcher>` element with value `INCLUDE`.
- **ERROR**: The request that is being processed with the error page mechanism specified in ”Error Handling” to an error resource matching the `<url-pattern>`. This is indicated by a `<dispatcher>` element with the value `ERROR`.
- **ASYNC**: The request is being processed with the async context dispatch mechanism specified in ”Asynchronous processing”  to a web component using a dispatch call.
  This is indicated by a `<dispatcher>` element with the value `ASYNC`.

Comment: Thanks... it worked for me. These all are the possible values?

Comment: Yes. @Mike. These all are possible values.

Comment: So REQUEST is the default value